# crontab rasberry pi con entornos virtuales

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, crontab

Hola amigos tengo un script en mi raspberry pi 4 y necesito que cuando se reinicie o se inicie se lance ese script desde crontab tengo la sigueinte configuracion pero no funciona tampoco me da ningun error es decir no hace nada espero me puedan ayudar amigos

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot sleep 5; cd /home/pi/.virtualenvs && source cv/bin/activate && python3 /home/pi/Documents/Alcoholimtro/alcoholimetro/main.py
```

espero me puedan ayudar por que necesito que active el entorno virtual que y ejecute el script de python que esta en el directorio. gracias amigos por la ayuda

Comment: ¿está crontab corriendo? ¿Has probado si un simple `echo "hola" > /tmp/bla` funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por multitud de cosas que no te esté funcionando, te doy algunas ideas.

1. En ubuntu se han reportado algunos bugs con el uso de `@reboot` por lo que yo utilizaría la sintaxis general de *minutos *horas , etc.
2. Chequea que tengas todos los permisos para la apertura, lectura y ejecución de los distintos archivos que uses
3. Puedes utilizar una sintaxis más sencilla y evitar pasar del **sh** al **bash** poniendo todo el comando de ejecución como si fuera la linea de comandos. Con esto te ahorras el `SHELL=/bin/bash`:

```
01 12 * * * /usr/bin/env bash -c 'cd /home/pi/.virtualenvs && source cv/bin/activate && python3 /home/pi/Documents/Alcoholimtro/alcoholimetro/main.py' > /home/ubuntu/alcoholimetro_log.txt 2>&1
```

**El comando general es**

```
01 12 * * * /usr/bin/env bash -c 'PON AQUÍ LAS EJECUCIONES' > /home/ubuntu/alcoholimetro_log.txt 2>&1
```

4. Especial atención a los últimos comandos que uso despues de las ejecuciones

```
> /home/ubuntu/alcoholimetro_log.txt 2>&1
```

Esto quiere decir que en ese archivo, voy a crear un `.txt` que va a contener el output de mi programa, si contiene una traza de error puedes ver lo que pone y solucionarás el problema.

**Este último punto es el más importante** ya que te permite saber los errores que ocurren